# Recursion so confusing

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write an program to accept a full name(i.e. `first name, middle name and lastname`) and display the initials along with the surname using RECURSION.

Sample-

Input: Subhas Chandra Bose
Output: S.C.Bose

```
import java.io.*;
class scbose {
    String st, st1;
    int d, l;
    scbose() {
        st = "", st = "";
        d = 0, l = 0;
    }
    String shortname(String str) {


        if (l < str.length()) {
            if (str.charAt(l) == 32) {

                st = st + str.charAt(d) + ".";
                d = l + 1;
            }
            l++;
            shortname(str);
        }
        st = st + str.substring(d);
        return st;

    }
}
```

But when I use the input `subhas chandra bose`, the output is like this `s.c.bosebosebosebosebose`...

What is the problem in this recursion program?

Comment: Ok, at least it is clear what the result should be. Was it your intention, that l and d are not local variables? And are you aware that shortname() is always called with the same parameter value? What is st1 for? Why is shortname() returning something, but it is never used in the recursion?

Comment: My advice:  start again, and don't rely on any instance level variables.

Answer (score 0):

For using recursion, you should be able to split your problem into similar smaller problems. You know the `fib` classical example.

Using the same, you might want your recursion to be something like this:

```
shortname(str) = str if str doesn't contain spaces
                 firstchar(str) + "." + shortname(str after removing the fist word and trimming it)
```

Like @stephen mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't be using instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

The line `st = st + str.substring(d);` is executing each time in a loop. i.e. you are adding last name everytime in the loop.

You cannot use recursion for two purposes.

Rather you can do something like this:

```
class scbose {
    String st, st1;
    static int d, l;
    scbose() {
        st = "";
        st1 = "";
        d = 0;
        l = 0;
    }
    String shortname(String str) {
        if (l < str.length()) {
            if (str.charAt(l) == 32) {

                st = st + str.charAt(d) + ". ";
                d = l + 1;
            }
            l++;
            shortname(str);
        }
        return st;

    }
    String lastname(String abc){
        String last =abc.substring(d);
        return last;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        scbose sc = new scbose();
        String check = "subhas chandra bose";
        System.out.println(sc.shortname(check)+sc.lastname(check));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `else`:

```
String shortname(String str) {
    if (l < str.length()) {
        if (str.charAt(l) == ' ') {
            st = st + str.charAt(d) + ".";
            d = l + 1;
        }
        l++;
        shortname(str);
    } else {
        st = st + str.substring(d);
    }
    return st;
}
```

If you don't put `st = st + str.substring(d);` inside an `else` block, the statement is executed **once per recursive call** and not only **when the end of the `String` is reached**.

This task is better done **not** using recursion, since the recursive version is much harder to understand and less efficient than a simple loop.

Also it's easier to read a program that uses `char` literals instread of character codes written as numbers (better use `' '` instead of `32`).

Comment: Oh! Yeah! Thanks! :-)